# Save view or map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, maps

Is there a way to save the current shapefile, raster, etc selections in QGIS and then bring them up all at once later? For example, I find myself re-creating maps over and over because I need different shapefiles or labels or colors. I would like to save the current extent and selection I have so I can quickly reference back to a map I've already made.

Is my question clear? I have tried asking The Google but can't seem to phrase it right.

Comment: Simply create and save a project.

Comment: This sounds like you are interested in creating different outputs, are you aware that it is possible to create print composers with different layer selections and styling? Atlases are also useful for creating different outputs.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know of a project in QGIS (the QGS file) like SecludedPath suggests.

If you (on Windows) save a project in the folder C:\Users\USERNAME.qgis2\project_templates. It will be available in the menu Project > New From Template > your project. If you want to quick access for using that project as a starter for a new project.

Answer (score 2):

You should just save current project (ctrl+s for save, ctrl+shift+s to save as)

After that you can load your project (style, layers etc.) whenever you want.

Comment: This is a good point. A saved project will save your layers, styles, and extents.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to save the extents within the project.

You can also save a "bookmark".

This can be accessed from View> Show Bookmarks.

If you want to save the layers that are visible, this can be done with "presets". Accessed from the eye at the top of the layers panel.

Comment: This won't allow different styles for each layer, but would be my preferred choice as it removes the need for duplicate files. If different styles are required for different circumstances it would be worth considering using rule based styling and the expression builder.